# Want to add random string to identifier line in fasta file

Tags: perl, random, addition, identifier, fasta

I want to add random string to existing identifier line in fasta file. 
So I get:

```
MMETSP0259|AmphidiniumcarteCMP1314aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
```

Then the sequence on the next lines as normal. I am have problem with i think in the format output. This is what I get:

```
MMETSP0259|AmphidiniumCMP1314aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
CTTCATCGCACATGGATAACTGTGTACCTGACTaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
TCTGGGAAAGGTTGCTATCATGAGTCATAGAATaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaac
```

It's added to every line. (I altered length to fit here.) I want just to add to the identifier line.

This is what i have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my $currentId = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa";

my $header_line;
my $seq;
my $uniqueID;

open (my $fh,"$ARGV[0]") or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
open (my $out_fh, ">$ARGV[0]_longer_ID_MMETSP.fasta");

while( <$fh> ){
    if ($_ =~ m/^(\S+)\s+(.*)/) {
        $header_line = $1;
        $seq = $2;
        $uniqueID = $currentId++;
        print $out_fh "$header_line$uniqueID\n$seq";
    } # if
} # while

close $fh;
close $out_fh;
```

Thanks very much, any ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program isn't working because the regex `^(\S+)\s+(.*)` matches every line in the input file. For instance, `\S+` matches `CTTCATCGCACATGGATAACTGTGTACCTGACT`; the newline at the end of the line matches `\s+`; and nothing matches `.*`.

Here's how I would encode your solution. It simply appends `$current_id` to the end of any line that contains a pipe `|` character

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;
use autodie;

my ($filename) = @ARGV;

my $current_id = 'a' x 57;

open my $in_fh,  '<', $filename;
open my $out_fh, '>', "${filename}_longer_ID_MMETSP.fasta";

while ( my $line = <$in_fh> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line .= $current_id if $line =~ tr/|//;
    print $line, "\n";
}

close $out_fh;
```

**output**

```
MMETSP0259|AmphidiniumCMP1314aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
CTTCATCGCACATGGATAACTGTGTACCTGACT
TCTGGGAAAGGTTGCTATCATGAGTCATAGAAT
```